# MySql SHOW query in ZEND

Tags: mysql, zend-framework, zend-db

In zend it is written like

```
$table = $this->getTable();
        $select = $table->select()->where('status = ?',1)
                                ->where('columnOne= ?', 1) 
                                ->order('columnTwo')
                                ->limit(1);
```

similar to where, order, limit conditions how can I condition for `LIKE`?

**My query is**

> **`SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'tableName'`**

I tried in this way

```
    $table = $this->getTable();
                $query= $table->select("TABLE STATUS")
                                ->like($table);
    $id = mysql_query($query);
```

then I found that no method for `LIKE` is available in ZEND.
Then How can I write above query in Zend framerk?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: fish through the methods in the core class. I swear I remember using a static method to get a list of all tables in a specific schema. But I cannot find anything in the documentation.

Comment: @Alan B. Dee  : there is no object or method for SHOW statement like SELECT statement nor for **`LIKE` opererator** like WHERE operator.

Comment: @Alan: there is a listTables() method on the db adapter which is probably what you are referring to.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This works for me, so hopefully it should give you what you want:

```
$stmt = $dbAdapter->query("SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE '$tableName';");
$tableStatus = $stmt->fetchObject();
```